# Use spring Transactional in a Prototype bean

Tags: spring, transactional

I would like to use spring transaction management capabilities within a prototype bean. I did the following:

- I've used `javax.inject.Provider` to create my prototype bean.
- I've annotated the method of the prototyped bean with the `@Transactional` annotation.

Is this the right way of doing it?

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private Provider<SomePrototype> myPrototypeProvider;

    public void execute() {
        SomePrototype somePrototype = myPrototypeProvider.get();
        somePrototype.someMethod();
    }

}





@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class SomePrototype {

    @Autowired
    private SomeSpringBean someSpringBean;
    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void someMethod() {
        Result result = someSpringBean.doSomething();
        someRepository.save(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation of transaction-scoped bean requires a proxy. Therefore, if we define a transactional bean as prototype, every that bean is requested, a new proxy is created, and that is not efficient.
What is reason behind this requirement (to have transactional prototype bean)